# Как на CSS установить шрифт для всех букв и символов?

Tags: html, css, шрифты

Что то типа "`font: url(http://site.ru/font.ttf)`"?

Comment: очень советую пользоваться http://www.google.com/webfonts

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@media screen {
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Ubuntu'), url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/ubuntu/v1/c2KTkZ_oLp2UOMwi4GGs9A.woff') format('woff');
}
}
html{font-family:Ubuntu}
```

Это пример со шрифтом Ubuntu в формате woff

Comment: ставьте как лучший ответ, или плюсик, чтобы не висело

Comment: Ага, поставил.